# $M_p \cong N_p$ for all prime ideals $p$, but $M \not \cong N$

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization, dedekind-domain

I am asked to find an example of a ring $R$ and $R$-module $M$ and $N$ such that $M_p \cong N_p$ for all prime ideal $P$ in $R$ but $M$ is not isomorphic to $N$.

My idea is as follows: Recall that if $S$ is a multiplicative subset of a commutative ring $R$ with identity and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $S^{-1}I = S^{-1}R$ if and only if $S \cap I \neq \emptyset$. For reference, this is Theorem 4.8 in Chapter 3 of Hungerford's algebra. I have seen people suggest that if $R$ is a non-principal Dedekind domain and $I\subset R$ a non-principal ideal, then for every prime ideal $p$ of $R$ and $S = R\setminus p$, we know that $S \cap I \neq \emptyset$. Why is this the case? Once this is known, the result immediately follows.

For a concrete example, recall that $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is a Dedekind domain. Furthermore, $I = (x-1,y)$ cannot be generated by a single element.

Note that $M_p = S^{-1}M$, where $S = R \setminus p$.

Comment: $R=M=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}], N=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ or any non-principal ideal of a  Dedekind domain should work.
$M\not \cong N$ (as $N$ isn't generated by one element) but $N_p$ is an ideal in the PID $R_p$ so $N_p=a_p R_p\cong R_p=M_p$.

Comment: $S^{-1}I=S^{-1}R$ isn't the same as $S^{-1}I\cong S^{-1}R$ !

Comment: @reuns How do we know that $a_pR_p\cong R_p $?

Comment: That's the case for any integral domain $B$ and $a\ne 0 \in B$, $b\to ab$ is a $B$-module isomorphism $B\to aB$

Comment: @reuns Hmm, that doesn't seem to hold when  we have $B = \mathbb{Z}$ and $2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $2\mathbb{Z}  \not \cong \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Isomorphic as $B$-module, not as ring.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you!